# How to do an ajax request with large parameters?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webrick

I am getting 'Request-URI Too Large' error when I tried to call a rails controller function from javascript with a large json parameter. I'm using Webrick http server. Is there any way to resolve this without changing the server?

I have something like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'application/get_list',
    data: { options : options_json, selected_option : selected_option_string},
    success: function(data) {
    // Insert the data to a div (returned data is a select tag with options)
    },
    type: 'get'
});
```

Comment: Please post all relevant code so we recreate the error and thus better assist you.

Comment: Hi @Regis, modified the post.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest fix would be to change it to a `POST` request, and set up the action to handle that, and then you won't run into this error.

If you need to it to be a `GET` request, you can add a file called `webrick.rb` to the `config\initializers` directory with this content:

```
if defined?(WEBrick::HTTPRequest)
    WEBrick::HTTPRequest.const_set("MAX_URI_LENGTH", 10240)
end
```

and if you keep getting the error, keep increasing the number `10240` until it works.

Since your comment says it needs to be a `GET` request, you really have no option but to set the `MAX_URI_LENGTH`.  From the [WEBrick source](https://www.omniref.com/ruby/2.2.1/symbols/WEBrick::HTTPRequest::MAX_URI_LENGTH#line=410):

```
if @request_line.bytesize >= MAX_URI_LENGTH and @request_line[-1, 1] != LF
    raise HTTPStatus::RequestURITooLarge
end
```

If you need really long URI's, then set it to something absurd, like 9223372036854775807

Comment: I need it to be a get request. Also, I'm not sure about changing the size of MAX_URI_LENGTH because the data that I'm passing can be really large.